# What tag should we use for challenges about manipulating files and directories?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we don't have a tag for challenges which are about dealing with the file system (checking for files, creating directories, moving files, etc.).

I believe we should create one, but I thought there was no obvious choice for a name. So I thought, let's do a good ol' meta poll. I'll add a few suggestions. Please vote according to your preferences and add your own suggestions.

Once there is a clear consensus I will accept the relevant answer and slowly start retagging old challenges.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We should create a tag [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system).

Comment: +1 (I can't vote.)

Comment: Looks like a pretty clear consensus to me.

Answer (score 5):

We should create a tag [file-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-manipulation).

Answer (score 4):

We should create a tag [file-system-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system-manipulation).

Comment: +1 (I can't vote.)

Comment: I think this one is too long. It's even longer than my ha-ha-only-serious suggestion of [danger-will-robinson].

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Well it's not *technically* too long. ;) (The maximum is 25 characters, this has 24.) Also, auto-completion means you don't really have to type it out, and I think it's very clear and encompasses both files and directories. (And is in line with [tag:array-manipulation].)

Comment: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: The advantage of several words in a tag is that starting to type any one of them will trigger the auto-completion.

Answer (score 3):

We should create separate tags [files](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) and [directories](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directories). Challenges which involve the manipulation of both can use both tags.

Comment: +1 (I can't vote.)

Answer (score 0):

We should create a tag [danger-will-robinson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danger-will-robinson).

Comment: I feel like I'm too young to get a reference here. :P

Comment: Oh, I'm really just commenting on that fact that _running_ a submission of this sort could cause data loss for you if the code is [buggy](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3671) (or untrustworthy). :-) Then again, I guess that applies to submissions of all categories, so.

Comment: Erm, more so because of the fact that I don't know who Will Robinson is. Should I? Or should I get off your lawn? ;)

Comment: I don't know who Will Robinson is, actually. It's not just you. It's just a common saying I've heard in various places and figured it must be a meme of some sort.

Comment: it's from Lost in Space

Answer (score -4):

We should create a tag [file-systems](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-systems) (note the plural).

Answer (score -6):

There is no need for such a tag.

Comment: -1 (I can't vote.)